# Authorization Scheme Changes not reflected in application

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm setting up a simple Authorization Scheme in my application using the Scheme Type "PL/SQL Function Returning Boolean" but if I make a change to the PL/SQL Function that change doesn't take effect unless I copy the schema into a new one.  How is the authorization result stored/cached in Apex?

I used the simplest example as seen below returning false, and then changing return to true but It still allows access.  I've also tried evaluaing "once per page view ' and 'once per session view, but neither works. The code I have tried is below:

```
Begin
  return( FALSE );
end;
```

This correctly provides the error message that I don't have access but if I change the code to

```
Begin
  return( TRUE );
end;
```

I still get the error message that I don't have access.  If I make an new authorization scheme that returns TRUE, I can access the app fine.

I would expect if I update the scheme, the change would be reflected in the application.  What am I missing? I feel like I am not understanding something about how APEX validates the Authorization scheme. I am using Apex 4.2.

Comment: Strange ... I created the authorization schema and I define how it should work (PL / SQL). So I go to the properties of the application in the "security" tab and say that my application should use that authorization scheme. And everything works as expected.

Comment: That works for me also but if I then go and update the authorization schema to return the opposite Boolean the application appears as though the authorization scheme wasn't changed.

Comment: I always use the option "Once per session", so when I change something in this PL/SQL, I refresh the application cleaning the session number, executing the url just with the app_id or alias and the page. f?p=myapp:mypage . But the other options should works, but I never needed to use them

Comment: This will also do the job apex_authorization.reset_cache; But it seems odd the 'once per page view' didn't reset the value